# MPMediaQuery not showing name in cell text label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have a playlist query that shows playlists, and is supposed to print them into the text label in my cell. However, I don't see any text displayed on my cell.

I have a NSLog that shows the playlist name. Help? My code is as follows.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];  


    MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];  
    NSArray *Playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];  

    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [[Playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem];  

    cell.textLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];  

    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in Playlists) {  
        NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);  
    }  
    return cell;  
}
```

Any guesses as to why my Cells aren't showing the names? I have the text as black on white cells. Alpha is 1.0

Comment: Yeah, just did. I have it NSLogged...and its showing in my Xcode console. I can select the cell as if it were showing the label. But I don't see the actual text.

I added a line within the code to ensure it shows. 
Cell.textLabel.alpha = 1.0;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to assign the playlist object from the collection, instead of the MPMediaItem object.  To verify, try printing this object the cell is created:

NSLog (@"%@", [playlistItem valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];  


MPMediaQuery *myPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];  
NSArray *Playlists = [myPlaylistsQuery collections];  

MPMediaPlaylist *playlistItem = [Playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

NSLog (@"%@", [playlistItem valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);

cell.textLabel.text = [playlistItem valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];  

for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in Playlists) {  
    NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);  
}  
return cell;  
}
```

Comment: I did set my delegates in the view did load method. No outcome difference came.

Keep in mind that NSLog is getting the name of my playlists, and it is getting them. Because I can see the playlist names in the console. So the code is grabbing the name of playlists...but not setting the label title.

Comment: Your NSLog is referencing a playlist object, not the MPMediaItem *rowItem object you're trying to load into the text property.  Also, it appears there is no MPMediaItem property called "MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName".  Instead, what about using: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle for testing purposes?

Comment: When I used MPMediaPropertyTitle I got the first song in the text label. That makes sense now...but what I don't understand now is how am I querying the first song in the playlist? My query is the MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery. Wouldn't that query playlists names? Is it because of the Collections that I have in the NSArray?

Comment: The playlistQuery is setup right, but it looks like you're assigning MPMediaItem, when you might need to use MPMediaPlaylist.  Try using MPMediaPlaylist  *playlistItem = [[Playlist objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] representativeItem];